# Extract a substring and take second value in a Bigquery Column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this data:

```
id  val
1   ajkdks - jkdj
2   djs - djsd
```

I want to take only the second value. Which is:

```
id val
1  jkdj
2  djsd
```

I know the query if using MySQL:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, " - ", 2)," - ",-1)
```

But what the query if i using bigquery?

Answer (score 2):

Use below

```
select id, split(val, ' - ')[safe_offset(1)] val
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We could phrase this using `REGEXP_EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT id, REGEXP_EXTRACT(val, r'[^ -]+$') AS val
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

Note that the above regex approach is also robust to the case where `val` might not have any hyphen separator, in which case the entire value would be returned.